# How read more XSD schemas with Xpath?

Tags: java, xpath, xsd, element

I have 2 XSD schemas first.xsd and second.xsd
In first.xsd is:

```
<xs:include schemaLocation="second.xsd" />
```

and I want read elements in second.xsd.
I have defined:

```
DocumentBuilder builder =  builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document xmlDocument = builder.parse(new FileInputStream("first.xsd"));
XPath xPath =  XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
NodeList result1 = null;
result1 = (NodeList) xPath.compile("//element[@name='List']").evaluate(xmlDocument, XPathConstants.NODESET);
for (int k = 0; k < result1.getLength(); k++) {
Element ele = (Element)result1.item(k);
System.out.println(ele.getAttribute("type")); }
```

Problem is program didnt find element list in second.xsd.
Can I define some as this?

```
Document xmlDocument = builder.parse(new FileInputStream("first.xsd","second.xsd"));
```

Is something as LSResourceResolver but that is for validation.
Can I use it for my code?
Thank you for advices.